# No warning from CMake when not including sources with `target_sources`

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project which depends on `foo.cpp`

```
add_library(App SHARED app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(App Module)
target_sources(App PRIVATE foo.cpp)
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app App)
```

which works perfectly. However if I remove line 3 to have

```
add_library(App SHARED app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(App Module)
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app App)
```

Then CMake does not give any warning in the either the configure or build stage. The only error I get is when running the eventual binary

```
./build/src/app/app: symbol lookup error: ./build/src/app/app: undefined symbol: _Z5startiPPc
```

Can I avoid this to get warnings/errors more up-front?

Comment: Why do you expect a warning from CMake? It cannot possibly know that part of your implementation is in `foo.cpp` if you don't write it explicitly.

Comment: This would require `CMake` to be telepathic, given that `add_library(App SHARED app.cpp foo.cpp)` would make `target_sources()` redundant. And how would it know you don't need `target_sources(app bar.cpp)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I avoid this to get warnings/errors more up-front?

Do you mean you want to get those errors during the build stage? You can't. That is a loader error, which basically means that it was unable to find the referenced symbol because the library was not found or something. And no there is no way to avoid it.

Suppose you build and run an application which runs correctly and then you go ahead and move or delete the libraries it is linking to you will suddenly get this error. As you can imagine, no one can warn you about this.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is it possible to get some warnings from the link stage? My understanding of the toolchain isn't great but I'm using Ninja and GCC.

Comment: No, linker only gives errors. During the linking stage you don't have the luxury of getting warned that something *might not be okay*. And usually, linker errors can be a pain to debug.

Comment: Ok, but I don't even get an error in this case. Is that unavoidable?

Comment: Ah sorry, I just re read the question. I am wrong. That's not a linker error, it's a loader error. Which is saying that it is unable to find the referenced symbol

Comment: And yes, it is unavoidable but it is fixable.